# JSON not being parsed by jQuery (error given)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have checked other questions akin to this one, and in those that I saw, the problem was either invalid JSON or something wrong with the headers on the XMLHttpRequest. AFAIK, mine is neither.

I have a [server that gives me valid json](http://futdata.esy.es/data.php?type=json). However, when I do this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://futdata.esy.es/data.php',
            data: {
                'type': 'json'
            },
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                console.log($.parseJSON(response));
            }
        });
```

I get this:

`[{"a":"a", "b":"b"}]
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token`

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why can't you just use the response?  You don't need to use $.parseJSON(response).

Comment: jQuery already parses the Json for you, you are trying to do it twice

Comment: The response is a string, I need it parsed.

Comment: jQuery will, by default, perform an *intelligent guess* if no `dataType` is given. So, `response` may already be parsed. Check `typeof response`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Butbutbut, when I do console.log, it gives me a string, not a JSON object.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski console.log(typeof(response)) gives `string`.

Comment: @meda console.log(typeof(response)) gives `string`.

Comment: your headers are wrong on the data.php?type=json, the response header says `text/html`, should be `application/json`, then jQuery will do all the work for you

Comment: @OJay Even if the headers say it's text, that's not a reason for why $.parseJSON fails.

Comment: @Bluefire you have JSON work with it , no need to reparse

Comment: @meda You're confusing JSON with actual JS objects. If the response is a string, it has to be parsed before it can be used.

Comment: @meda Again I repeat, it is **not** JSON, console.log(typeof(response)) says that it's a string.

Comment: @Bluefire I posted this earlier but deleted it: if you're *sure* you've got a string, then it may be that your server code is including a Unicode space character (or some other non-printing character) in the response. That's often what causes those "Unexpected token" errors that don't seem to include the token in question.

Comment: @Pointy Could I use a for loop to print my string char by char to see whether that's true or not?

Comment: there is a funny hidden/whitespace character before the first `{`. Server is doing something funny to the _json_ which means it can't be parsed. How are you output the _json_ from the server, `json_encode`?

Comment: @@@@@@ Sorry everyone, I got it, the problem was with my PHP, it inserted a '' into my string D:

Comment: @Bluefire yes that's one way to check - just call `.charCodeAt()` for each character in the string and look for something weird.

Comment: @Pointy it was the `$out[0] = ''` in my code. I never knew that '' was a separate char, though.

Comment: @meda: JSON can only exist in JavaScript inside a string. Of course it has to be parsed to an object or array first.

Comment: @Bluefire: It is JSON and that's why it has to be parsed. See my previous comment ^.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah I realized that, please excuze my js ignorance, Im more server side programmer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There appears to be a `NUL` character within the response:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
// "[\u0000{\"a\":\"a\", \"b\":\"b\"}]"
//   ^^^^^^
```

Though it's within the whitespace, `JSON.parse()` or `$.parseJSON()` still isn't expecting it.

Remove that and it should parse fine.

Comment: Thanks! I guessed that it was my way of shaving off the string's 1st char that did this (`$out[0] = ''`), removed it, and now it works. Well, that's a lesson learned.